# Can't update object in the list on C#

Tags: c#

I'm building a page updating a object from a list.

When I'm posting a form

```
public class MyController: Controller
{

  List<Item> ItemList = new List<Item>();

  // Constructor
  public MyController()
  {
    // initialize the list with testing data
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Post(Item item)
  {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      var tempItem = ItemList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == item.Id);           
      tempItem.Name = "Something Else";
      return View("Edit", tempItem);                
    }
  }
}
```

I found the updated tempItem is not shown as updated on the Edit page. After all, the item in the list has not been changed at all.

Have I done anything wrong?

Comment: What is `ItemList`? Where does it come from? How is it defined? Where do you save changes?

Comment: Where did `ItemList` come from here? What is the type of the items in this list? Is this a `class`? or a `struct`? Does the `"Something Else"` appear in the rendered output?

Comment: @spender it's a list created within the controller class.

Comment: @Marc Gravell yes it's a list of Item, declared in a class. "Something Else" is not being shown on page.

Comment: You do understand that your controller is newed up by MVC for **every request**? If you need persistent data, you'll need to back your list off onto a database. Don't be tempted to save state in the webserver. It's like storing data on quicksand.

Comment: @spender I still don't understand why 'return View' with explicit model passing failed.

Comment: is this your complete code of action?

Comment: because this will not even compile

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad no this is not complete code. I'm just focusing whether I can adjust the user's input from a post form, and show on the confirmation page.